# How to have vagrant/chef push a local git repo to a server

Tags: git, chef-infra, vagrant

I have a vagrant/chef/Berksfile configuration (at https://github.com/jaycrossler/geoevents-chef-repo/blob/master/cookbooks/geoevents/attributes/default.rb#L5) that is set to pull code from a checked-in github repo. It works great, and every time I run 'vagrant provision', it updates the code from github into the VM.

```
default['geoevents']['git_repo']['location'] = 'https://github.com/jaycrossler/geo-events.git'
```

How do I point the chef recipe to instead point to a local git instance, such as ~/app/geo-events.git so that when I make local changes, I can push to the VM for testing? Also, is this the best workflow?

Answer (score 3):

If you either copy your repository below the cookbook folder or add an additional [synced folder](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/) to Vagrant, you have access to the code on your host.

Newer versions of Chef (at least 11.8, maybe already 11.6) have the whole file-based providers rewritten and they should also accept `file:///` urls. If you did not add an additional synced folder, you can access your code through `file:///vagrant/geoevents-repo`, which is below the `vagrant` synced folder pointing to your cookbook folder, existing by default. This has now to be set as the new location by passing JSON data to the chef provisioner in `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.json = {
    :geoevents => {
      :git_repo => {
        :location => "file:///vagrant/geoevents-repo"
      }
    }
  }
```

If you add an additional synced folder, you, of course, have to adjust the URL.

**EDIT**: As you write that it does not work with `chef.json`, try the following chef role, place it e.g. in `roles/geoevents_local.rb` and add it to your run list (in the `Vagrantfile`):

```
name "geoevents_local"

override_attributes(
  "geoevents" => {
    "git_repo" => {
      "location" => "file:///vagrant/geoevents-repo"
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that approach and it only partially worked for me.  I set up [config.vm.synced_folder "../geoevents", "/vagrant/geoevents-repo"], which worked great (thanks!), but when I did the chef.json piece you recommend, it still points to the online repo.  Things do work if I either ssh in and create a simlink to that new directory, or put that location in the recipe directly... but the Vagrantfile setting doesn't seem to overwrite the one in attributes/default.rb

Comment: That's weird. I would expect that it overrides, wouldn't make so much sense otherwise. Can you create a chef [role](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html) that overrides this attribute?.

Comment: Did you "reload" the instance after you setup the shared folder? Vagrant only adds the shares at boot.

Comment: He wrote that the synced folder thing worked for him. But did you really reload the VM *and* provision it? Newer versions of Vagrant (IIRC 1.3+) do not automatically provision on reload anymore. That might be why the repo still points to the old location (without looking up, I'm not even sure, if the `git` resource will change the source, if the ref already matches, so better also delete the old repo in the VM).

Comment: Yeah, I rebuilt the entire server to test. 'vagrant destroy', 'vagrant up', 'vagrant provision'.  I'm reading through the role documentation now, looks like the best solution. Will let you know - thanks for all the guidance.